# FPDF error "Unable to create output file"

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm working with fpdf libray for providing pdf files. A part of my project consists of using this library to generate pdf files for consumers.
We are working with a server test under "ovh". The arborescence of my space in "ovh" is : /www/betatest.

A folder named upload which contains factures's folder where all the facture's pdf files will be there.
So, when i try to generate a pdf file inside the factures folder, in a web browser it displays me :

**Warning**: fopen(upload/factures/facture_98.pdf) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Success in /homez.742/coplayer/www/betatest/library/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 1025

**FPDF error:** Unable to create output file: upload/factures/facture_98.pdf.

I tried a lot of things that i found in this web site but does not work.
Please help me. Thank's a lot! :)

Comment: What are the permissions of the `factures` directory ? Try with `755`

Comment: I tried with 755 but the message that is displayed is still the same

Comment: Well, go for a brutal `777` to see if the problem is here. It might also be an owner issue. Make sure it is the right path though... Show us your `PHP` code please

Comment: http://codebin.org/view/a6a77c55

Comment: i tried a brutatl 777 but it is still the same error message that is displayed.

Comment: Try this : `$nomFacture = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."upload/factures/facture_".$idFacture.".pdf";`

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the directory have at least a `755`. Also, use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with your path to target the good directory :

```
$nomFacture = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."upload/factures/facture_".$idFacture.".pdf";
```

That will produce something like

> /homez.742/coplayer/www/betatest/upload/factures/facture_12.pdf

Comment: Warning: fopen(/homez.742/coplayer/www/betatest/upload/factures/facture_114.pdf) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Success in /homez.742/coplayer/www/betatest/library/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 1025
FPDF error: Unable to create output file: /homez.742/coplayer/www/betatest/upload/factures/facture_114.pdf

Comment: Even with making the directory 755

Comment: @user2567806 do you have any documentation of your "pdf" class ? It could be outputing this because you don't open the file with `w+` (read and write)

Comment: i'm using the fpdf class that we can found in this web site : http://www.fpdf.org/, that can be donwloaded freely

Comment: Ok you will need to try modifying the file `fpdf.php`. At the line 1025 you have `$f = fopen($name,'wb');`. Change this to `$f = fopen($name,'w+');`

Comment: If this didn't work, it could be a "safe mode" issue with ovh. Try to see if you have this kind of option you could disable. If not, try removing the "factures" directory and make it with the php script : `mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."upload/factures/", 0777);`

Comment: I modified the parameter of the fopen function inside the fpdf.php but a got the same message again

Comment: @user2567806 Then undo the changes in this file.

Comment: i did it but i have the same error message, localy with wampserver it works well !

Comment: Output a `phpinfo();` and find the line with `safe_mode`. Is it "off" ?

Comment: - Brewal : yes i found that safe_mode is off, do i need to change it ?

Comment: @user2567806 No it should be off. Sorry I think I tried everything I can on this one. Hope someone else with other ideas will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending times for this -Brewal. Please do you know other libraries that can i use for generating pdf files ?

Comment: I have good echoes of [`Zend_Pdf`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/fr/zend.pdf.html). I assume you are french ? :)

Comment: Oui Brewal ;). Merci pour le lien.

Comment: But i need to install the framework and i'm working with CakePHP, i won't to change the framework for a library it is constrainting.

Comment: It should not be a problem. You should take a look at this : [How to use Zend Framework in CakePHP](http://cakephptips.blogspot.fr/2008/03/howto-use-zend-framework-in-cakephp_7464.html). Or [This](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf) !

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have not sending to output something else (like `echo`, `var_dump`, *etc.*) before generating PDF with `Output("path_file", "F")`. **It is mandatory.**

Answer (score -1):

make sure that file **upload/factures/facture_98.pdf** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.