# mPDF error: Unable to create output file

Tags: php, mpdf, html-to-pdf

I am Using [mPDF](http://mpdf1.com/mpdf/) to generate pdf from an html.

On my localhost the pdf is generated to the located directory successfully.
But not on Server, although I have open the permissions of that directory.

```
chmod -R 0777 /mydirectory
```

Found  [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515162/fpdf-error-unable-to-create-output-file#comment27250480_18527894) from an answer and changed `fopen($file_out,'wb');` to `fopen($file_out,'w+');` in mpdf.php

But no success.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try not to modify the source. Instead, revert back to `fopen($file_out,'wb');` and make sure that folder permissions are set to `0777`, like you did.

Also, check if you're using the *absolute path* in order to write to a file, rather than using relative paths or even worse, URL.

So,

`$file  = "/var/www/html/mywebsite/mypdfs/myfile.pdf";`

and try if it works.

Good luck!

Comment: Having same issue, and file_path i am passing is absolute.  still getting the issue.. Unable to create output file: /var/www/path_to_my_file/my_file.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message.

The problem for me was that I was saving a file with a filename that had invalid characters.

I created this function to replace invalid characters with usable characters:

```
// Function to replace disallowed characters from file name.
function fixFileName($file_name) {
    // $file_name = str_replace("\\", "\\", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("/", " ", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace(">", "\>", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("<", "\<", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("|", "\|", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace(":", "\:", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("&", "\&", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("(", "\(", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace(")", "\)", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace(";", "\;", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("*", "\*", $file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("?", "\?", $file_name);
    return $file_name;
}
```

Hope this helps if someone else runs into this issue. I wasn't sure about the backslash, so I commented it out.

Comment: More simple:
```php
function fixFileName($file_name) {
    $disallowed_chars = ["\\", "/", ">", "<", "|", ":", "&", "(", ")", ";", "*", "?"];
    return str_replace($disallowed_chars, "\\" . implode("\\", $disallowed_chars), $file_name);
}
```